# Почему не корректно работает фильтрация?

Tags: javascript

```js
    function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b){
        arr.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (element < a || element > b) arr.splice(index, 1)
        });
        return arr;
    }

    console.log(filterRangeInPlace([1, 4, 6, 10, 3, -2], 1, 4));
```

Данная функция удаляет из массива элементы, которые меньше чем a или больше чем b. То есть оставляет элементы которые входят в диапазон от a до b. Но при a = 1, b = 4 функция оставляет в массиве 10.

Answer (score 3):

Вы меняете массив во время прохождения цикла, вот индекс и сбивается. воспльзуйтесь методом filter

```js
function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b){
  return arr.filter(element => (element >= a && element <= b));
    }

console.log(filterRangeInPlace([1, 4, 6, 10, 3, -2], 1, 4));
```

---

а так со splice

```js
   function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b){
   for(index=arr.length; --index;)
       if (arr[index] < a || arr[index] > b) 
           arr.splice(index, 1)
    return arr;
}

console.log(filterRangeInPlace([1, 4, 6, 10, 3, -2], 1, 4));
```

---

если вы хотите изменять исходный массив

```js
function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b){
   for(index=arr.length; --index;)
       if (arr[index] < a || arr[index] > b) 
           arr.splice(index, 1)
}
arr = [1, 4, 6, 10, 3, -2]
filterRangeInPlace(arr, 1, 4)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Мне нужно изменить исходный массив, а не вернуть новый

Comment: тогда идите с конца в начало

Comment: @user374742 обновил ответ